# Floor Function and Euler-Mascheroni Constant

Tags: integers, ceiling-and-floor-functions, square-numbers

I need to know how to express the following function, $\lfloor{\sqrt{c^2-707}}\rfloor^2=y$  $(s.t.$ $c $ and $y$ are in $N)$, analytically.  I think http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions
might help.